# How to setup vscode-remote on Windows 10 without Docker Desktop?

Tags: vscode-remote

I've been using [VSCode's remote containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) capabilities for some time - such a helpful extension.  Problem is, Docker Desktop changed their licensing model and devs are being told not to install it on our machines anymore.

Does anybody know how to setup vscode-remote on a Win 10 system without Docker Desktop?
Is there a way to use other container engines?  This could be directly installing on Windows OS or installing on WSL2.

Also, could somebody from MSFT update the [remote containers setup instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) to reflect this alternative approach?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3534